# Как отследить нажатия одной кнопки а потом другой?

Tags: javascript

Надо сначала отследить нажатие на <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, а потом сочетание клавиш <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>.
Вот пример:

```
if (e.code == "CapsLock") {
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 18) {
          alert();
        }
      }
```

Но этот код не работает.

Comment: либо через флаг, что капс был нажат, либо при нажатии капса помещать значение в пул нажатых клавиш и смотреть, что значение пула последнее или имеется в пуле.

Comment: необходимо отслеживать нажатие на элементе какого типа (input, p, div...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете отследить нажатие `caps-lock` и нужных клавиш `alt` + `ctrl` через `keydown`.
Так же он работает и с `keyup`.
При использовании же `keyPress` Вы не получите event о нажатии.

Соответственно, чтобы проверить нажатие `ctrl + alt` при включенном `Caps-lock` - Вы можете воспользоваться следующим решением:

```js
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
        var caps = event.getModifierState && event.getModifierState('CapsLock');
        if(caps){
            if(event.key == 'Alt' && event.ctrlKey){
                console.log('Включен Caps-lock, зажат Ctrl и нажат Alt');
            }
        }
    });
```